# Facebook Open Graph tags not being used when sharing an article

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've added a Facebook 'Share' button to my site, but when the window opens, there are absolutly no details about the page that is being shared.

I've included several meta tags in the header, and added the XML parsers to the `<HTML>` tag -

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xml:lang="en-GB" dir="ltr">
<head>

    <meta property='og:image' content="http://test.dynedrewett.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/dyne-drewett-logo.gif"/>
    <meta property='og:locale' content='en_UK'/>
    <meta property='og:title' content='Consumer protection law - Dyne Drewett'/>
    <meta property='og:description' content='The OFT conducted a review of 156 retailer websites, and found that many of them may not be complying fully with the Consumer Protection Regulations.'/>
    <meta property='og:url' content='http://test.dynedrewett.com/consumer-protection-law-and-the-internet/'/>
    <meta property='og:site_name' content='Dyne Drewett'/>
    <meta property='og:type' content='article'/>
```

Does anybody know why this would not be working? Thanks.

Comment: Neither the debug tool nor my browser can access the URL you’ve given as `og:url` value.

Comment: Thaks @CBroe - my issue was that I was testing on a local server, so FB couldn't scrape any information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta tags are fine for an overall website, but for sharing individual pages/items within specific sites I recommend using the [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).  Customizing params per whatever it is you are sharing.  This requires a basic FB app and javascript SDK but is definitely the way to go.

Theoretically what you're doing should work but I've noticed that facebook will cache those metas at the domain or subdomain level.  For that you can also check out the url debugger [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.dynedrewett.com%2Fconsumer-protection-law-and-the-internet%2F)

Comment: The debug tool led me to the answer - this site is not yet published, but on a local server, and FB told me that it couldn't scrape any info. As soon as I put it live (well, on a testing URL), it all worked fine. Thanks for the link!!